# Getting NodeJS to run on FreeBSD as a Supervisor-PCM process

Tags: freebsd, node.js, supervisord

**What I'm trying to do:**
I'm trying to create a small webhooks_server using 3 technologies:

- a FreeBSD server
- a NodeJS server
- a process control syster (Supervisor)

When I run my test code on the FreeBSD server using `node <main.js>`

```
function intervalFunc() {
   console.log('Cant stop me now!');
}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 1500);
```

It works just fine:

[image]

**Problem:**
As soon as I add this test-file into a Supervisor process:

```
;;;;;; webhooks_server ;;;;;;;
[program:webhooks_server]
command=/usr/local/bin/node /home/<usr_name>/apps/webhooks_server/test.js
process_name=%(program_name)s
directory=/home/<usr_name>/apps/webhooks_server
user=<usr_name>
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I get "radio-silence", meaning: nothing shows up on the "stdout" or "stderr" channels. Furthermore, I have also tried to perform an I/O (writing to a log-file) operation and  also doesn't happen (no error - just "quiet").

On my local machine all code works fine, so I suspect this is a FreeBSD/Supervisor setup problem.

**Question:**
What am I missing? Any suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: Do you have supervisord running?

Comment: @arrowd, yes; I can start, restart, stop (etc) processes using "supervisorctl"